# Outlook 2011: where are mail message in my archive file stored?

Tags: macos, ms-office

I use Outlook to access Exchange.  I store old mail in an Outlook Archive folder. I know that Outlook 2011 stores data in `/Users/<user>/Documents/Microsoft User Data` but where exactly are these Archive emails stored on my computer?

The reason I'm asking is because I want to provide the path to my archive files to my cloud backup program and exclude all the other Outlook files that are available/stored on the Exchange server.

Comment: There are not stored anywhere if you did not do it. There is no Archiving like in Windows, but there are simular or better ways.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook 2011 for MAC stores only the indices in a database file and stores the data records (individual emails) as a series of files nested within folders. The Database file and its folders are located here:

~/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2011 Identities/Main Identity/Database
~/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2011 Identities/Main Identity/Data Records

Adding these path's to your backup strategy should address your issue.

Comment: Don't the paths above include all messages? If so, that's NOT what I'm looking for.  I'm only interested in the messages that are "ON MY COMPUTER" and not the copies of the messages that are also on the Exchange server.  IOW, I don't want the messages that are part of my Inbox, Sent Items, etc.  I just want the messages that I archived.

Comment: So amplification on this question. Outlook 2011 for OSX does not include a native mechanism for archiving email (ala Outlook on PC). Are you using an Outlook rule to accomplish this?

Comment: An Outlook 2011 rule to autoarchive would be nice to have but I'm really looking for a pattern to let me backup program know which files/messages to back up (the data that stored "ON MY COMPUTER" in Outlook 2011) and which to exclude (the mail that's mirrored on the Exchange server)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it explains it quite well.
http://www.arxnetworks.com/news/tag/backup-emails-in-outlook-for-mac/

**Since there is more than one way doing this: here is an alternative that might suit you better**.

In the Category create a Archive (if it is not there already).

When reading a email that you want to archive click on the category and select archive.

In the File menu select Export!

Looks like this:

[image]
[image]

That will make a file where you want it containing only archived emails.

**Drawback-->** you can not keep adding new emails to the same archived file.